# How do I cast an NSDictionary to a swift dictionary if the NSDictionary has integers for keys

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary stored in a Plist that has an imbedded dictionary in it. If I use strings as the keys I can use the code below to cast it to a swift dictionary:

```
let namesDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
var names = namesDict as [String: [String : String]]
```

However if I try to use integers as the keys in the root dictionary I can't get it to work. The code below doesn't work and returns this error: "value type is not bridged to Objective-C"

```
let namesDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
var names = namesDict as [Int: [String : String]]
```

I have tried intValue, but that doesn't work either. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Apple's NSDictionary reference:

> In general, a key can be any object (provided that it conforms to the
>   NSCopying protocol—see below), but note that when using key-value
>   coding the key must be a string (see Key-Value Coding Fundamentals).

Plist are Key-Value coding compliant

Comment: Thank you. I assumed NSDictionary would be the same as Swift dictionaries which can take integers as their keys. Here is a quote from Apples guide to Swift 2.1: "This example creates an empty dictionary of type [Int: String] to store human-readable names of integer values. Its keys are of type Int, and its values are of type String."